# How to get tensorflow Tensor size in bytes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

Let's say I have a very simple variable:

```
my_var = tf.get_variable("my_var", (100,))
```

I would like to be able to compute the size (not shape) in bytes of the Tensor. Naturally it depends on the dtype.

I haven't found any way in doing in the official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the size in bytes of the Tensor using [slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim).

The following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import slim

my_var = tf.get_variable("my_var", (100,))
slim.model_analyzer.analyze_vars([my_var], print_info=True)
```

outputs:

```
---------
Variables: name (type shape) [size]
---------
my_var:0 (float32_ref 100) [100, bytes: 400]
Total size of variables: 100
Total bytes of variables: 400
```

You can get  more information of course in the [slim github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim). Have fun!

Comment: That's exactly the kind of things I was looking for. Thank you so much

Comment: Now for Tf 2  , slim is a separated package :  pip install tf-slim

Comment: How would I calculate bytes of eagorTensor?